# Android Studio - attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am making my first Android app and I am a complete novice when it comes to working with Java as I have only ever used Python. I am trying to create a database that stores the user's details through an initial set up activity, however I am getting an error

```
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:        java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/fitness.essentials.fitnessessentials/databases/UserData.db
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:525)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at fitness.essentials.fitnessessentials.Database.<init>(Database.java:26)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at fitness.essentials.fitnessessentials.SetupScreen.onCreate(SetupScreen.java:44)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
08-13 17:24:27.400 10263-10263/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the database class main bits

```
// Constructor method
    public Database(Context context) {
    // Superclass constructor called to create database
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase());
}

// On create the databases are created (if they don't exist)
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER);
    db.close();
}

// Currently no special treatment for upgrading or downgrading the schema
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  }
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  }


/*               Shorthand methods for generic tasks              */
// Add a single row of user data
public long addUserData(String name, String gender, String dob, String height, float currentweightNum,
                        float targetweightNum, String activitylevel, String weightdifference) {
    // Get database that is readable
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Define row values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_GENDER, gender);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_DOB, dob);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_HEIGHT, height);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_CURRENT_WEIGHT, currentweightNum);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_TARGET_WEIGHT, targetweightNum);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_ACTIVITY_LEVEL, activitylevel);
    values.put(DataContract.UserColumns.COLUMN_WEIGHT_DIFFERENCE, weightdifference);


    // Insert values into the database, in the user data table
    long newRowId = db.insert(
            DataContract.UserColumns.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            values);

    db.close();
    // Return the row id that the data was inserted into
    return newRowId;
}
```

And here is the setup screen class that I am trying to add the details from

```
public class SetupScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private String Name;
private String Gender;
private String Height;
private String CurrentWeight;
private String TargetWeight;
private String DOB;
private String ActivityLevel;
private String WeightDifference;

private Database dbhelper;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup_screen);
    Name = "";
    Gender = "";
    Height = "";
    CurrentWeight = "";
    TargetWeight = "";
    DOB = "";
    ActivityLevel = "";
    WeightDifference = "";


    dbhelper = new Database(getApplicationContext());





    Spinner spinnerGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGender);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterGender = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterGender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerGender.setAdapter(adapterGender);

    spinnerGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner spinnerActivityLevel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerActivityLevel);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterActivity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.activity_level, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterActivity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerActivityLevel.setAdapter(adapterActivity);

    spinnerActivityLevel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner spinnerWeightDifference = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerWeightDifference);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterWeight = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.weight_difference, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterWeight.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerWeightDifference.setAdapter(adapterWeight);

    spinnerWeightDifference.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Gender = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    ActivityLevel = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    WeightDifference = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // An interface callback
}

public void save(View view) {


    Name = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name)).getText().toString();
    DOB = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.DOB)).getText().toString();
    Height = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.Height)).getText().toString();
    CurrentWeight = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.CurrentWeight)).getText().toString();
    TargetWeight = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.TargetWeight)).getText().toString();


    if (Name.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (Gender.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gender cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (DOB.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DOB cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (Height.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Height cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (CurrentWeight.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Current weight cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Float CurrentWeightNum = Float.parseFloat(CurrentWeight);
    if (CurrentWeightNum < 43.0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current weight is not supported by this application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TargetWeight.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Target weight cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Float TargetWeightNum = Float.parseFloat(TargetWeight);
    if (TargetWeightNum > 93.0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your target weight is not supported by this application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (ActivityLevel.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity level cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (WeightDifference.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Weight difference cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (CurrentWeightNum.equals(TargetWeightNum)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Current and target weight can not be the same!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    dbhelper.addUserData(Name, Gender, DOB, Height, CurrentWeightNum, TargetWeightNum, ActivityLevel, WeightDifference);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

}

Sorry if formatting is not correct, the application currently does not open, however when I remove the dbhelper stuff in the set up screen class the application runs but crashes when I try to press enter which calls the adding data method. I have investigated the issue but can not see where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Try removing ` db.close();` from the `onCreate` method of the database class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USER);
    db.close(); // remove this line
}
```

And also this:

```
onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase());
```

From onUpgrade() method, add:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + YOUR_TABLE_NAME);
onCreate(db);
```

Comment: This fixed it thank you very much! Can I just ask, I can see why 'db.close();' could cause an error, I should have seen this but what exactly does removing the 'onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase())' in context to my application do? I am constantly learning by reading through code and getting others help so I really appreciate it!

Comment: @KyleOsborne hmm. Working with DB we usually have 3 steps: 1. Open connection 2. Do domething with DB 3. Close connection. By writing  separate methods to do these 3 steps will help you to control your DB easier. You can easily know when your database open or when it closed. Learning programming is similar to learn math, one problem might has many method to solve :) 
You were not wrong, just don't need to call onCreate because it will be call automatically everytime you initialize the instance of DB helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase());` from Constructor. No need to call this explicitly.

`OnCreate()` callback called, when the `database` is created for the first time.